# - UPDATED - Rails API app create multiple nested records of a different models at once using POST request from the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, post

I'm working on an API Ruby on rails 6.1 application, so all of my responses are in JSON. I'm trying to create a level 3 Nested records, meaning I want to create a plan record which contains many days records which contains many meals on each day.

**Plan.rb**

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :days
    has_and_belongs_to_many :meals
    has_one_attached :image, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :meals, reject_if: ->(object) { object[:name].blank? }
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :days, reject_if: ->(object) { object[:number].blank? }
end
```

**Day.rb**

```
class Day < ApplicationRecord
     has_and_belongs_to_many :plans
     has_and_belongs_to_many :meals
     validates_presence_of :number, on: [:create, :update], message: "can't be blank"
     validates_uniqueness_of :number, on: [:create, :update], message: "You can't use same day number twice"
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :meals, reject_if: ->(object) { object[:name].blank? }
end
```

**Meal.rb**

```
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :days
  has_and_belongs_to_many :plans
end
```

i also added 2 more join tables

```
  create_table "days_meals", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
     t.bigint "day_id", null: false
     t.bigint "meal_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "days_plans", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
     t.bigint "day_id", null: false
     t.bigint "plan_id", null: false
  end
```

and this is the **UPDATED** method inside **plans_controller.rb**

```
# POST /create_custon_plan
 def create_custon_plan
    @plan = Plan.new(plan_params)

    if @plan.save
      render json: {
        messages: "Plan was successfully created.",
        is_success: true,
        status: :created,
        data: { plan: @plan, days_attributes: @plan.days, meals_attributes: @plan.meals },
      }
    else
      render json: @plan.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

This is how i permit my params

```
def plan_params
    params.require(:plan).permit(:name, :monthly_price, :image_url, days_attributes: [:number, meals_attributes: [:name, :calories, :protein, :fat, :carbohydrates, :categorie]])
end
```

This is my **POST** request Body to **http://localhost:3000/api/create_custon_plan**

```
{
    "name": "Test Plan",
    "monthly_price": 0,
    "image_url": "55555",
    "days_attributes": [
                {
                "number": 500,
                "meals_attributes": [
                            {
                                "name": "azerazer Salad",
                                "calories": 55,
                                "protein": 55,
                                "fat": 55,
                                "carbohydrates": 55,
                                "image_url": "55555",
                                "categorie": "snack-1"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Fit Burger",
                                "calories": 55,
                                "protein": 55,
                                "fat": 55,
                                "carbohydrates": 55,
                                "image_url": "55555",
                                "categorie": "meal-1"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Vegan Rataouille",
                                "calories": 55,
                                "protein": 55,
                                "fat": 55,
                                "carbohydrates": 55,
                                "image_url": "55555",
                                "categorie": "snack-2"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Chicken BBQ",
                                "calories": 55,
                                "protein": 55,
                                "fat": 55,
                                "carbohydrates": 55,
                                "image_url": "55555",
                                "categorie": "meal-3"
                            }
                        ]
                },
                {
                "number": 502,
                "meals_attributes": 
                        [
                            {
                                "name": "Woldrof Salad",
                                "calories": 55,
                                "protein": 55,
                                "fat": 55,
                                "carbohydrates": 55,
                                "image_url": "55555",
                                "categorie": "snack-1"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Baked Beef",
                                "calories": 55,
                                "protein": 55,
                                "fat": 55,
                                "carbohydrates": 55,
                                "image_url": "55555",
                                "categorie": "meal-1"
                            }
                        ]
                }
            ]
}
```

so far the nested day works fine but the nested meals inside the nested days doesn't anyideas how to fix that ? even the logs inside the terminals completely ignores it

Comment: Can you try printing out `day.valid?`, also does day have any callbacks in the model like `before_save`?

Comment: This is a little unrelated but you should move all that logic from the controller into models, that code is very difficult to read, it has so many conditionals and repeated code in the JSON responses. You could probably benefit from writing everything in a Active Record transaction block where you can rollback all the inserts if one of the child objects fail to insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop on them and create them individually. `Plan.new(plan_params)` should do the work, you just need to specify the nested attributes properly.

Changes:

1. `days` to `day_attributes`
2. Dont need to pass ids.

For example:

```
{
"name": "Test Plan",
"monthly_price": 0,
"image_url": null,
"day_attributes": [
            {
            "number": 1,
            "meal_attributes": [
                        {
                            "name": "Kale Salad",
                            "calories": null,
                            "protein": null,
                            "fat": null,
                            "carbohydrates": null,
                            "image_url": null,
                            "categorie": "snack-1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Fit Burger",
                            "calories": null,
                            "protein": null,
                            "fat": null,
                            "carbohydrates": null,
                            "image_url": null,
                            "categorie": "meal-1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Vegan Rataouille",
                            "calories": null,
                            "protein": null,
                            "fat": null,
                            "carbohydrates": null,
                            "image_url": null,
                            "categorie": "snack-2"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Chicken BBQ",
                            "calories": null,
                            "protein": null,
                            "fat": null,
                            "carbohydrates": null,
                            "image_url": null,
                            "categorie": "meal-3"
                        }
                    ]
            },
            {
            "number": 2,
            "meal_attributes": 
                    [
                        {
                            "name": "Woldrof Salad",
                            "calories": null,
                            "protein": null,
                            "fat": null,
                            "carbohydrates": null,
                            "image_url": null,
                            "categorie": "snack-1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Baked Beef",
                            "calories": null,
                            "protein": null,
                            "fat": null,
                            "carbohydrates": null,
                            "image_url": null,
                            "categorie": "meal-1"
                        }
                    ]
            }
        ]
```

}

Also you should mention them properly in permit params as well like:

```
params.permit(:name, :monthly_price, :image_url, day_attributes: [:number, meal_attributes: [:name, :calories, :protein, :fat, :carbohydrates, :image_url, :categorie]])
```

For more info you can refer to:

[Active Record Nested Attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

[Railscasts #196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed informations , however it seems i'm doing something wrong here since the 3rd level doesn't save, if my example here, the plan and day saves perfectly as expected to be, yet the 3rd level " meals " is completely ignored, by the console and the json response it's always an empty array, any ideas about that ?

Comment: and maybe could u please check out the relationships between the table how it should be, since i made some changes to optimize the database, `class Plan < ApplicationRecord has_and_belongs_to_many :days has_and_belongs_to_many :meals   accepts_nested_attributes_for :meals  accepts_nested_attributes_for :days end` , `class Day < ApplicationRecord has_and_belongs_to_many :days has_and_belongs_to_many :meals end` , `class Meal < ApplicationRecord has_and_belongs_to_many :days has_and_belongs_to_many :meals end`

Comment: Try moving `accepts_nested_attributes_for :meals` from `plan.rb` to `day.rb`

Comment: You can also refer to the railscasts episode 196, you will find the same example. Have added a link above.

Comment: i tried that along many other things yet nothing works, i'm checking rails cast episode at this moment maybe it will help

Comment: sadly, it doesn't really help since he was focusing on the form on the view side on that episode.

Comment: Try debugging and check params if the meals are present or not.